# Is it possible to see if PWA was installed from the APP Store vs. Mobile Browsing?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

At the moment my Mobile experience is m-web and my app is PWA (app stores) ... but I want to join the two and just have PWA.

But I need to differentiate between the App Store download and the Mobile download - at least for the first few usages. (i.e. if someone downloads from the app store, I want to "hide" certain content until they have purchased, however if they access direct from mobile, they can have the content directly.)

Is this possible with PWA - to see if the version they have was downloaded from the APP store vs downloaded through mobile browsing?

Comment: but can you publish PWA in App store? I thought you can do it only with mobile version.

Comment: You may want to do some research on PWA vs TWA. A plain PWA is not installed from an App Store.

Answer (score 1):

1. You do not need to submit your PWA to the app store. Users can just access it directly.
2. You can wrap your PWA in a hybrid shell, something like the soon to be deprecated Cordova for example. If you do this, I believe there would be some sort of flag to check if the shell is present.
3. Apple is known for rejecting and removing hybrid apps, just FYI. This one reason why so many brands are abandoning native apps.

It feels like you are doing something of #3.

I get why you want users to pay through your web interface, the 30% tax is repressive. But doing this will most likely get you tossed from the app store. This is the foundation of BaseCamp's complaints.

https://love2dev.com/apple-appstore-pwa/

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches) {
  console.log("This is running as standalone.");
}
```

Sure you need to edit `standalone` if you use some other display property

Comment: the standalone check indicates the PWA was opened from the home screen icon and is in full screen mode, not the borwser.